# Scala - How to pass a string value to a data frame filter (Spark-Shell)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

I am using Spark 2.2.0 and Scala 2.11.8 in the Spark-Shell environment.
I have a data frame df, and I need to filter out the previous day's data based on the value of column 'date' and then append the data to a HDFS location. (e.g. today is 2018-06-28, I need the data of 2018-06-27)

Below is the code:

```
 df.filter($"date" === "2018-06-27") .write.mode(SaveMode.Append).parquet("hdfs:/path..../date=2018-06-27")
```

> I need the code above for automation, so I need to replace
>   "2018-06-27" for the filter value as well as the directory name.
>   So if I have a string -> date_test: String = 2018-06-27; 
>   The code below should be still working

```
 df.filter($"date" === "date_test") .write.mode(SaveMode.Append).parquet("hdfs:/path..../date=date_test")
```

How to do this?

Comment: What is the data type of your date column date or string

Comment: The type of the date column is string

Comment: why the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply filter conditions like below

```
//Input
+----------+
|      date|
+----------+
|2018-02-01|
|2017-01-02|
+----------+

//Solution: 
 val previousDate="'2018-02-01'"
 df.filter(s"date=$previousDate").show

//Output: 
+----------+
|      date|
+----------+
|2018-02-01|
+----------+
```

You can do like this for your solution

```
 val datetest:String="2018-02-01"
 df.filter(s"date='$datetest'").write.mode(SaveMode.Append).parquet(s"hdfs:/path..../$datetest")
```

Comment: So for automation purpose, It cannot contain the actually date '2018-02-01'. For example, if I have a string   datetest: String = 2018-02-01. The code should be able to work like df.filter("date='datetest'").show

Comment: I modified answer you need to create your filter condition like datetest: String = "'2018-02-01'"

Comment: This works for the filter, but does it work for the directory name as well?

Comment: No, It will not work .Please see last part of answer It will work fine

Comment: Cool, I'll try it.